# CSS Animation for panel sliding Animation not working

Tags: html, css, animation

While rewriting entirely my UI, simplifying a lot of the old markup (and thus the JavaScript that powers it up) I've found a problem I can't fix.

One of the many components is a panel that slides above another. I've extracted that part as follows:

```js
$( '#preview' ).addClass( 'open' )

$( '#preview .navigation .open-panel .fa' ).on( 'click', function() {
 $( '#inner' ).removeClass( 'open' ).addClass( 'open' );
});

$( '#inner .navigation .close-panel .fa' ).on( 'click', function() {
   $( '#inner' ).addClass( 'closed' ).removeClass( 'open' )
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 10vh !important;
}

#preview {
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 0.7vw;
    /*bottom: 0;*/
    display: none;
    height: 80vh; /** 91.6vh */
    /*left: 0;*/
    /*margin: auto;*/
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*right: 0;*/
    /*top: 0;*/
    width: 31.3vw;
    /*z-index: 4;*/
    
    background-color: blue;
}

  #preview.open {
      animation-name: fadeIn;
      animation-duration: 400ms;
      animation-fill-mode: both;

      display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
      display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
      display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
      display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
      display: flex;
  }

#preview .navigation {
    position: absolute;
    /*z-index: 7;*/
}

    #preview .navigation .open-panel {
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-left: none !important;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5vw;
        border-top-right-radius: 0.5vw;
    }

        #preview .navigation .open-panel .fa {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 6vh;
            margin: 2.1vh 0.25vw 1.45vh 0.4vw;
        }
        
#inner {
    align-items: center;
    /*bottom: 0;*/

    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;

    height: 80vh;
    left: -62.6vw; /** 2x `#preview` width, but negative */
    /*margin: auto;*/
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*right: 0;*/
    /*top: 0;*/
    width: 31.3vw;
    /*z-index: 8;*/
    
    background-color: red;
}

  #inner.open {
    animation-name: slideInLeft;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    left: 0;
  }

  #inner.closed {
    animation-name: slideInRight;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    left: -62.6vw;
  }
    
#inner .navigation {
    right: 0 !important;
    /*z-index: 9;*/
}

    #inner .navigation .close-panel {
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-right: none !important;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5vw;
        border-top-left-radius: 0.5vw;
    }

        #inner .close-panel .fa {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 6vh;
            margin: 2.1vh 0.4vw 1.45vh 0.25vw;
        }
        










































































/*!
 * animate.css -http://daneden.me/animate
 * Version - 3.5.2
 * Licensed under the MIT license - http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2017 Daniel Eden
 */

.animated{animation-duration:1s;animation-fill-mode:both}.animated.infinite{animation-iteration-count:infinite}.animated.hinge{animation-duration:2s}.animated.bounceIn,.animated.bounceOut,.animated.flipOutX,.animated.flipOutY{animation-duration:.75s}@keyframes bounce{0%,20%,53%,80%,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);transform:translateZ(0)}40%,43%{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.755,.05,.855,.06);transform:translate3d(0,-30px,0)}70%{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.755,.05,.855,.06);transform:translate3d(0,-15px,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(0,-4px,0)}}.bounce{animation-name:bounce;transform-origin:center bottom}@keyframes flash{0%,50%,to{opacity:1}25%,75%{opacity:0}}.flash{animation-name:flash}@keyframes pulse{0%{transform:scaleX(1)}50%{transform:scale3d(1.05,1.05,1.05)}to{transform:scaleX(1)}}.pulse{animation-name:pulse}@keyframes rubberBand{0%{transform:scaleX(1)}30%{transform:scale3d(1.25,.75,1)}40%{transform:scale3d(.75,1.25,1)}50%{transform:scale3d(1.15,.85,1)}65%{transform:scale3d(.95,1.05,1)}75%{transform:scale3d(1.05,.95,1)}to{transform:scaleX(1)}}.rubberBand{animation-name:rubberBand}@keyframes shake{0%,to{transform:translateZ(0)}10%,30%,50%,70%,90%{transform:translate3d(-10px,0,0)}20%,40%,60%,80%{transform:translate3d(10px,0,0)}}.shake{animation-name:shake}@keyframes headShake{0%{transform:translateX(0)}6.5%{transform:translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg)}18.5%{transform:translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg)}31.5%{transform:translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg)}43.5%{transform:translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg)}50%{transform:translateX(0)}}.headShake{animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;animation-name:headShake}@keyframes swing{20%{transform:rotate(15deg)}40%{transform:rotate(-10deg)}60%{transform:rotate(5deg)}80%{transform:rotate(-5deg)}to{transform:rotate(0deg)}}.swing{transform-origin:top center;animation-name:swing}@keyframes tada{0%{transform:scaleX(1)}10%,20%{transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9) rotate(-3deg)}30%,50%,70%,90%{transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1) rotate(3deg)}40%,60%,80%{transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1) rotate(-3deg)}to{transform:scaleX(1)}}.tada{animation-name:tada}@keyframes wobble{0%{transform:none}15%{transform:translate3d(-25%,0,0) rotate(-5deg)}30%{transform:translate3d(20%,0,0) rotate(3deg)}45%{transform:translate3d(-15%,0,0) rotate(-3deg)}60%{transform:translate3d(10%,0,0) rotate(2deg)}75%{transform:translate3d(-5%,0,0) rotate(-1deg)}to{transform:none}}.wobble{animation-name:wobble}@keyframes jello{0%,11.1%,to{transform:none}22.2%{transform:skewX(-12.5deg) skewY(-12.5deg)}33.3%{transform:skewX(6.25deg) skewY(6.25deg)}44.4%{transform:skewX(-3.125deg) skewY(-3.125deg)}55.5%{transform:skewX(1.5625deg) skewY(1.5625deg)}66.6%{transform:skewX(-.78125deg) skewY(-.78125deg)}77.7%{transform:skewX(.390625deg) skewY(.390625deg)}88.8%{transform:skewX(-.1953125deg) skewY(-.1953125deg)}}.jello{animation-name:jello;transform-origin:center}@keyframes bounceIn{0%,20%,40%,60%,80%,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}20%{transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1)}40%{transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(1.03,1.03,1.03)}80%{transform:scale3d(.97,.97,.97)}to{opacity:1;transform:scaleX(1)}}.bounceIn{animation-name:bounceIn}@keyframes bounceInDown{0%,60%,75%,90%,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-3000px,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,25px,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(0,-10px,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(0,5px,0)}to{transform:none}}.bounceInDown{animation-name:bounceInDown}@keyframes bounceInLeft{0%,60%,75%,90%,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-3000px,0,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(25px,0,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(-10px,0,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(5px,0,0)}to{transform:none}}.bounceInLeft{animation-name:bounceInLeft}@keyframes bounceInRight{0%,60%,75%,90%,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(3000px,0,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(-25px,0,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(10px,0,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(-5px,0,0)}to{transform:none}}.bounceInRight{animation-name:bounceInRight}@keyframes bounceInUp{0%,60%,75%,90%,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,3000px,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,-20px,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(0,10px,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(0,-5px,0)}to{transform:translateZ(0)}}.bounceInUp{animation-name:bounceInUp}@keyframes bounceOut{20%{transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9)}50%,55%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}}.bounceOut{animation-name:bounceOut}@keyframes bounceOutDown{20%{transform:translate3d(0,10px,0)}40%,45%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,-20px,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)}}.bounceOutDown{animation-name:bounceOutDown}@keyframes bounceOutLeft{20%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(20px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-2000px,0,0)}}.bounceOutLeft{animation-name:bounceOutLeft}@keyframes bounceOutRight{20%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(-20px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(2000px,0,0)}}.bounceOutRight{animation-name:bounceOutRight}@keyframes bounceOutUp{20%{transform:translate3d(0,-10px,0)}40%,45%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,20px,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-2000px,0)}}.bounceOutUp{animation-name:bounceOutUp}@keyframes fadeIn{0%{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}}.fadeIn{animation-name:fadeIn}@keyframes fadeInDown{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInDown{animation-name:fadeInDown}@keyframes fadeInDownBig{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-2000px,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInDownBig{animation-name:fadeInDownBig}@keyframes fadeInLeft{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInLeft{animation-name:fadeInLeft}@keyframes fadeInLeftBig{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-2000px,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInLeftBig{animation-name:fadeInLeftBig}@keyframes fadeInRight{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInRight{animation-name:fadeInRight}@keyframes fadeInRightBig{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(2000px,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInRightBig{animation-name:fadeInRightBig}@keyframes fadeInUp{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,100%,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInUp{animation-name:fadeInUp}@keyframes fadeInUpBig{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInUpBig{animation-name:fadeInUpBig}@keyframes fadeOut{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}.fadeOut{animation-name:fadeOut}@keyframes fadeOutDown{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,100%,0)}}.fadeOutDown{animation-name:fadeOutDown}@keyframes fadeOutDownBig{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)}}.fadeOutDownBig{animation-name:fadeOutDownBig}@keyframes fadeOutLeft{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)}}.fadeOutLeft{animation-name:fadeOutLeft}@keyframes fadeOutLeftBig{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-2000px,0,0)}}.fadeOutLeftBig{animation-name:fadeOutLeftBig}@keyframes fadeOutRight{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0)}}.fadeOutRight{animation-name:fadeOutRight}@keyframes fadeOutRightBig{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(2000px,0,0)}}.fadeOutRightBig{animation-name:fadeOutRightBig}@keyframes fadeOutUp{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)}}.fadeOutUp{animation-name:fadeOutUp}@keyframes fadeOutUpBig{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-2000px,0)}}.fadeOutUpBig{animation-name:fadeOutUpBig}@keyframes flip{0%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(-1turn);animation-timing-function:ease-out}40%{transform:perspective(400px) translateZ(150px) rotateY(-190deg);animation-timing-function:ease-out}50%{transform:perspective(400px) translateZ(150px) rotateY(-170deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in}80%{transform:perspective(400px) scale3d(.95,.95,.95);animation-timing-function:ease-in}to{transform:perspective(400px);animation-timing-function:ease-in}}.animated.flip{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible;backface-visibility:visible;animation-name:flip}@keyframes flipInX{0%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in;opacity:0}40%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateX(-20deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in}60%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateX(10deg);opacity:1}80%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateX(-5deg)}to{transform:perspective(400px)}}.flipInX{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important;animation-name:flipInX}@keyframes flipInY{0%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in;opacity:0}40%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(-20deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in}60%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(10deg);opacity:1}80%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(-5deg)}to{transform:perspective(400px)}}.flipInY{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important;animation-name:flipInY}@keyframes flipOutX{0%{transform:perspective(400px)}30%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateX(-20deg);opacity:1}to{transform:perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);opacity:0}}.flipOutX{animation-name:flipOutX;-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important}@keyframes flipOutY{0%{transform:perspective(400px)}30%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(-15deg);opacity:1}to{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);opacity:0}}.flipOutY{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important;animation-name:flipOutY}@keyframes lightSpeedIn{0%{transform:translate3d(100%,0,0) skewX(-30deg);opacity:0}60%{transform:skewX(20deg);opacity:1}80%{transform:skewX(-5deg);opacity:1}to{transform:none;opacity:1}}.lightSpeedIn{animation-name:lightSpeedIn;animation-timing-function:ease-out}@keyframes lightSpeedOut{0%{opacity:1}to{transform:translate3d(100%,0,0) skewX(30deg);opacity:0}}.lightSpeedOut{animation-name:lightSpeedOut;animation-timing-function:ease-in}@keyframes rotateIn{0%{transform-origin:center;transform:rotate(-200deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:center;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateIn{animation-name:rotateIn}@keyframes rotateInDownLeft{0%{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate(-45deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInDownLeft{animation-name:rotateInDownLeft}@keyframes rotateInDownRight{0%{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate(45deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInDownRight{animation-name:rotateInDownRight}@keyframes rotateInUpLeft{0%{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate(45deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInUpLeft{animation-name:rotateInUpLeft}@keyframes rotateInUpRight{0%{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate(-90deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInUpRight{animation-name:rotateInUpRight}@keyframes rotateOut{0%{transform-origin:center;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:center;transform:rotate(200deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOut{animation-name:rotateOut}@keyframes rotateOutDownLeft{0%{transform-origin:left bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate(45deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutDownLeft{animation-name:rotateOutDownLeft}@keyframes rotateOutDownRight{0%{transform-origin:right bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate(-45deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutDownRight{animation-name:rotateOutDownRight}@keyframes rotateOutUpLeft{0%{transform-origin:left bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate(-45deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutUpLeft{animation-name:rotateOutUpLeft}@keyframes rotateOutUpRight{0%{transform-origin:right bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate(90deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutUpRight{animation-name:rotateOutUpRight}@keyframes hinge{0%{transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}20%,60%{transform:rotate(80deg);transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}40%,80%{transform:rotate(60deg);transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;opacity:1}to{transform:translate3d(0,700px,0);opacity:0}}.hinge{animation-name:hinge}@keyframes jackInTheBox{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale(.1) rotate(30deg);transform-origin:center bottom}50%{transform:rotate(-10deg)}70%{transform:rotate(3deg)}to{opacity:1;transform:scale(1)}}.jackInTheBox{animation-name:jackInTheBox}@keyframes rollIn{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0) rotate(-120deg)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.rollIn{animation-name:rollIn}@keyframes rollOut{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate(120deg)}}.rollOut{animation-name:rollOut}@keyframes zoomIn{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}50%{opacity:1}}.zoomIn{animation-name:zoomIn}@keyframes zoomInDown{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,-1000px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInDown{animation-name:zoomInDown}@keyframes zoomInLeft{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(-1000px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(10px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInLeft{animation-name:zoomInLeft}@keyframes zoomInRight{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(1000px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(-10px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInRight{animation-name:zoomInRight}@keyframes zoomInUp{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,1000px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,-60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInUp{animation-name:zoomInUp}@keyframes zoomOut{0%{opacity:1}50%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}to{opacity:0}}.zoomOut{animation-name:zoomOut}@keyframes zoomOutDown{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,-60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,2000px,0);transform-origin:center bottom;animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomOutDown{animation-name:zoomOutDown}@keyframes zoomOutLeft{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(42px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale(.1) translate3d(-2000px,0,0);transform-origin:left center}}.zoomOutLeft{animation-name:zoomOutLeft}@keyframes zoomOutRight{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(-42px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale(.1) translate3d(2000px,0,0);transform-origin:right center}}.zoomOutRight{animation-name:zoomOutRight}@keyframes zoomOutUp{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,-2000px,0);transform-origin:center bottom;animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomOutUp{animation-name:zoomOutUp}@keyframes slideInDown{0%{transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translateZ(0)}}.slideInDown{animation-name:slideInDown}@keyframes slideInLeft{0%{transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translateZ(0)}}.slideInLeft{animation-name:slideInLeft}@keyframes slideInRight{0%{transform:translate3d(100%,0,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translateZ(0)}}.slideInRight{animation-name:slideInRight}@keyframes slideInUp{0%{transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translateZ(0)}}.slideInUp{animation-name:slideInUp}@keyframes slideOutDown{0%{transform:translateZ(0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(0,100%,0)}}.slideOutDown{animation-name:slideOutDown}@keyframes slideOutLeft{0%{transform:translateZ(0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)}}.slideOutLeft{animation-name:slideOutLeft}@keyframes slideOutRight{0%{transform:translateZ(0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0)}}.slideOutRight{animation-name:slideOutRight}@keyframes slideOutUp{0%{transform:translateZ(0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)}}.slideOutUp{animation-name:slideOutUp}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preview">

  <div class="navigation">

    <div class="open-panel border all">
      <span class="fa fa-chevron-right text"></span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center w-100 h-100 modal-wrapper">
    
    <div id="inner">

      <div class="navigation">

        <div class="close-panel border all">
          <span class="fa fa-chevron-left text"></span>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor blah, blah, blah...</div>

    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

> For some reason the clicking action doesn't work twice. In my UI it works fine ;)

The old UI was extremely complex for such little thing. In this rewriting I decided to take advantage of CSS Animations (blowing away compatibility wit old IEs) and the [Daneden's Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

The JavaScript just adds/removes certain classes to trigger the animations. For the opening it works fine, but for the closing it's pretty much ignored.

What could that be?

*Side notes*

As you can see there's a lot of rules commented.

I've kept them to show some of the real values of my code (widths, heights, z-indexes...) and some are reminiscences of an old attempt of box centering without Flexbox.

The Flexbox vendor prefixes are to make Firefox understand Flexbox (it was ignoring `display: flex`) o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed these two lines. 
`$( '#inner' ).removeClass( 'open' ).addClass( 'open' );` 
`$( '#inner' ).addClass( 'closed' ).removeClass( 'open' );` 
to this 
`$( '#inner' ).addClass( 'open' );` 
`$( '#inner' ).removeClass( 'open' );`

**EDIT:** 
The closing animation should now work properly. 
It will remove the class `closed` when it opens `$( '#inner' ).removeClass( 'closed' );`. 
It will add class `closed` when it closes. `$( '#inner' ).addClass( 'closed' );`
And use `animation-name: slideOutLeft;` for `#inner.closed` and everything will work properly!

```js
$( '#preview' ).addClass( 'open' );

$( '#preview .navigation .open-panel .fa' ).on( 'click', function() {
  $( '#inner' ).addClass( 'open' );
  $( '#inner' ).removeClass( 'closed' );
});

$( '#inner .navigation .close-panel .fa' ).on( 'click', function() {
    $( '#inner' ).addClass( 'closed' );
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 10vh !important;
}

#preview {
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 0.7vw;
    /*bottom: 0;*/
    display: none;
    height: 80vh; /** 91.6vh */
    /*left: 0;*/
    /*margin: auto;*/
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*right: 0;*/
    /*top: 0;*/
    width: 31.3vw;
    /*z-index: 4;*/
    
    background-color: blue;
}

  #preview.open {
      animation-name: fadeIn;
      animation-duration: 400ms;
      animation-fill-mode: both;

      display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
      display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
      display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
      display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
      display: flex;
  }

#preview .navigation {
    position: absolute;
    /*z-index: 7;*/
}

    #preview .navigation .open-panel {
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-left: none !important;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5vw;
        border-top-right-radius: 0.5vw;
    }

        #preview .navigation .open-panel .fa {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 6vh;
            margin: 2.1vh 0.25vw 1.45vh 0.4vw;
        }
        
#inner {
    align-items: center;
    /*bottom: 0;*/

    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;

    height: 80vh;
    left: -62.6vw; /** 2x `#preview` width, but negative */
    /*margin: auto;*/
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*right: 0;*/
    /*top: 0;*/
    width: 31.3vw;
    /*z-index: 8;*/
    
    background-color: red;
}

  #inner.open {
    animation-name: slideInLeft;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    left: 0;
  }

  #inner.closed {
    animation-name: slideOutLeft;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
    
#inner .navigation {
    right: 0 !important;
    /*z-index: 9;*/
}

    #inner .navigation .close-panel {
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-right: none !important;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5vw;
        border-top-left-radius: 0.5vw;
    }

        #inner .close-panel .fa {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 6vh;
            margin: 2.1vh 0.4vw 1.45vh 0.25vw;
        }
        










































































/*!
 * animate.css -http://daneden.me/animate
 * Version - 3.5.2
 * Licensed under the MIT license - http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2017 Daniel Eden
 */

.animated{animation-duration:1s;animation-fill-mode:both}.animated.infinite{animation-iteration-count:infinite}.animated.hinge{animation-duration:2s}.animated.bounceIn,.animated.bounceOut,.animated.flipOutX,.animated.flipOutY{animation-duration:.75s}@keyframes bounce{0%,20%,53%,80%,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);transform:translateZ(0)}40%,43%{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.755,.05,.855,.06);transform:translate3d(0,-30px,0)}70%{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.755,.05,.855,.06);transform:translate3d(0,-15px,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(0,-4px,0)}}.bounce{animation-name:bounce;transform-origin:center bottom}@keyframes flash{0%,50%,to{opacity:1}25%,75%{opacity:0}}.flash{animation-name:flash}@keyframes pulse{0%{transform:scaleX(1)}50%{transform:scale3d(1.05,1.05,1.05)}to{transform:scaleX(1)}}.pulse{animation-name:pulse}@keyframes rubberBand{0%{transform:scaleX(1)}30%{transform:scale3d(1.25,.75,1)}40%{transform:scale3d(.75,1.25,1)}50%{transform:scale3d(1.15,.85,1)}65%{transform:scale3d(.95,1.05,1)}75%{transform:scale3d(1.05,.95,1)}to{transform:scaleX(1)}}.rubberBand{animation-name:rubberBand}@keyframes shake{0%,to{transform:translateZ(0)}10%,30%,50%,70%,90%{transform:translate3d(-10px,0,0)}20%,40%,60%,80%{transform:translate3d(10px,0,0)}}.shake{animation-name:shake}@keyframes headShake{0%{transform:translateX(0)}6.5%{transform:translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg)}18.5%{transform:translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg)}31.5%{transform:translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg)}43.5%{transform:translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg)}50%{transform:translateX(0)}}.headShake{animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;animation-name:headShake}@keyframes swing{20%{transform:rotate(15deg)}40%{transform:rotate(-10deg)}60%{transform:rotate(5deg)}80%{transform:rotate(-5deg)}to{transform:rotate(0deg)}}.swing{transform-origin:top center;animation-name:swing}@keyframes tada{0%{transform:scaleX(1)}10%,20%{transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9) rotate(-3deg)}30%,50%,70%,90%{transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1) rotate(3deg)}40%,60%,80%{transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1) rotate(-3deg)}to{transform:scaleX(1)}}.tada{animation-name:tada}@keyframes wobble{0%{transform:none}15%{transform:translate3d(-25%,0,0) rotate(-5deg)}30%{transform:translate3d(20%,0,0) rotate(3deg)}45%{transform:translate3d(-15%,0,0) rotate(-3deg)}60%{transform:translate3d(10%,0,0) rotate(2deg)}75%{transform:translate3d(-5%,0,0) rotate(-1deg)}to{transform:none}}.wobble{animation-name:wobble}@keyframes jello{0%,11.1%,to{transform:none}22.2%{transform:skewX(-12.5deg) skewY(-12.5deg)}33.3%{transform:skewX(6.25deg) skewY(6.25deg)}44.4%{transform:skewX(-3.125deg) skewY(-3.125deg)}55.5%{transform:skewX(1.5625deg) skewY(1.5625deg)}66.6%{transform:skewX(-.78125deg) skewY(-.78125deg)}77.7%{transform:skewX(.390625deg) skewY(.390625deg)}88.8%{transform:skewX(-.1953125deg) skewY(-.1953125deg)}}.jello{animation-name:jello;transform-origin:center}@keyframes bounceIn{0%,20%,40%,60%,80%,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}20%{transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1)}40%{transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(1.03,1.03,1.03)}80%{transform:scale3d(.97,.97,.97)}to{opacity:1;transform:scaleX(1)}}.bounceIn{animation-name:bounceIn}@keyframes bounceInDown{0%,60%,75%,90%,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-3000px,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,25px,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(0,-10px,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(0,5px,0)}to{transform:none}}.bounceInDown{animation-name:bounceInDown}@keyframes bounceInLeft{0%,60%,75%,90%,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-3000px,0,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(25px,0,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(-10px,0,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(5px,0,0)}to{transform:none}}.bounceInLeft{animation-name:bounceInLeft}@keyframes bounceInRight{0%,60%,75%,90%,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(3000px,0,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(-25px,0,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(10px,0,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(-5px,0,0)}to{transform:none}}.bounceInRight{animation-name:bounceInRight}@keyframes bounceInUp{0%,60%,75%,90%,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,3000px,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,-20px,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(0,10px,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(0,-5px,0)}to{transform:translateZ(0)}}.bounceInUp{animation-name:bounceInUp}@keyframes bounceOut{20%{transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9)}50%,55%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}}.bounceOut{animation-name:bounceOut}@keyframes bounceOutDown{20%{transform:translate3d(0,10px,0)}40%,45%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,-20px,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)}}.bounceOutDown{animation-name:bounceOutDown}@keyframes bounceOutLeft{20%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(20px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-2000px,0,0)}}.bounceOutLeft{animation-name:bounceOutLeft}@keyframes bounceOutRight{20%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(-20px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(2000px,0,0)}}.bounceOutRight{animation-name:bounceOutRight}@keyframes bounceOutUp{20%{transform:translate3d(0,-10px,0)}40%,45%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,20px,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-2000px,0)}}.bounceOutUp{animation-name:bounceOutUp}@keyframes fadeIn{0%{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}}.fadeIn{animation-name:fadeIn}@keyframes fadeInDown{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInDown{animation-name:fadeInDown}@keyframes fadeInDownBig{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-2000px,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInDownBig{animation-name:fadeInDownBig}@keyframes fadeInLeft{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInLeft{animation-name:fadeInLeft}@keyframes fadeInLeftBig{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-2000px,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInLeftBig{animation-name:fadeInLeftBig}@keyframes fadeInRight{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInRight{animation-name:fadeInRight}@keyframes fadeInRightBig{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(2000px,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInRightBig{animation-name:fadeInRightBig}@keyframes fadeInUp{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,100%,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInUp{animation-name:fadeInUp}@keyframes fadeInUpBig{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInUpBig{animation-name:fadeInUpBig}@keyframes fadeOut{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}.fadeOut{animation-name:fadeOut}@keyframes fadeOutDown{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,100%,0)}}.fadeOutDown{animation-name:fadeOutDown}@keyframes fadeOutDownBig{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)}}.fadeOutDownBig{animation-name:fadeOutDownBig}@keyframes fadeOutLeft{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)}}.fadeOutLeft{animation-name:fadeOutLeft}@keyframes fadeOutLeftBig{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-2000px,0,0)}}.fadeOutLeftBig{animation-name:fadeOutLeftBig}@keyframes fadeOutRight{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0)}}.fadeOutRight{animation-name:fadeOutRight}@keyframes fadeOutRightBig{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(2000px,0,0)}}.fadeOutRightBig{animation-name:fadeOutRightBig}@keyframes fadeOutUp{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)}}.fadeOutUp{animation-name:fadeOutUp}@keyframes fadeOutUpBig{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-2000px,0)}}.fadeOutUpBig{animation-name:fadeOutUpBig}@keyframes flip{0%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(-1turn);animation-timing-function:ease-out}40%{transform:perspective(400px) translateZ(150px) rotateY(-190deg);animation-timing-function:ease-out}50%{transform:perspective(400px) translateZ(150px) rotateY(-170deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in}80%{transform:perspective(400px) scale3d(.95,.95,.95);animation-timing-function:ease-in}to{transform:perspective(400px);animation-timing-function:ease-in}}.animated.flip{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible;backface-visibility:visible;animation-name:flip}@keyframes flipInX{0%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in;opacity:0}40%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateX(-20deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in}60%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateX(10deg);opacity:1}80%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateX(-5deg)}to{transform:perspective(400px)}}.flipInX{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important;animation-name:flipInX}@keyframes flipInY{0%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in;opacity:0}40%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(-20deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in}60%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(10deg);opacity:1}80%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(-5deg)}to{transform:perspective(400px)}}.flipInY{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important;animation-name:flipInY}@keyframes flipOutX{0%{transform:perspective(400px)}30%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateX(-20deg);opacity:1}to{transform:perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);opacity:0}}.flipOutX{animation-name:flipOutX;-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important}@keyframes flipOutY{0%{transform:perspective(400px)}30%{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(-15deg);opacity:1}to{transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);opacity:0}}.flipOutY{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important;animation-name:flipOutY}@keyframes lightSpeedIn{0%{transform:translate3d(100%,0,0) skewX(-30deg);opacity:0}60%{transform:skewX(20deg);opacity:1}80%{transform:skewX(-5deg);opacity:1}to{transform:none;opacity:1}}.lightSpeedIn{animation-name:lightSpeedIn;animation-timing-function:ease-out}@keyframes lightSpeedOut{0%{opacity:1}to{transform:translate3d(100%,0,0) skewX(30deg);opacity:0}}.lightSpeedOut{animation-name:lightSpeedOut;animation-timing-function:ease-in}@keyframes rotateIn{0%{transform-origin:center;transform:rotate(-200deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:center;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateIn{animation-name:rotateIn}@keyframes rotateInDownLeft{0%{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate(-45deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInDownLeft{animation-name:rotateInDownLeft}@keyframes rotateInDownRight{0%{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate(45deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInDownRight{animation-name:rotateInDownRight}@keyframes rotateInUpLeft{0%{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate(45deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInUpLeft{animation-name:rotateInUpLeft}@keyframes rotateInUpRight{0%{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate(-90deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInUpRight{animation-name:rotateInUpRight}@keyframes rotateOut{0%{transform-origin:center;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:center;transform:rotate(200deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOut{animation-name:rotateOut}@keyframes rotateOutDownLeft{0%{transform-origin:left bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate(45deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutDownLeft{animation-name:rotateOutDownLeft}@keyframes rotateOutDownRight{0%{transform-origin:right bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate(-45deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutDownRight{animation-name:rotateOutDownRight}@keyframes rotateOutUpLeft{0%{transform-origin:left bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate(-45deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutUpLeft{animation-name:rotateOutUpLeft}@keyframes rotateOutUpRight{0%{transform-origin:right bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate(90deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutUpRight{animation-name:rotateOutUpRight}@keyframes hinge{0%{transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}20%,60%{transform:rotate(80deg);transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}40%,80%{transform:rotate(60deg);transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;opacity:1}to{transform:translate3d(0,700px,0);opacity:0}}.hinge{animation-name:hinge}@keyframes jackInTheBox{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale(.1) rotate(30deg);transform-origin:center bottom}50%{transform:rotate(-10deg)}70%{transform:rotate(3deg)}to{opacity:1;transform:scale(1)}}.jackInTheBox{animation-name:jackInTheBox}@keyframes rollIn{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0) rotate(-120deg)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.rollIn{animation-name:rollIn}@keyframes rollOut{0%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate(120deg)}}.rollOut{animation-name:rollOut}@keyframes zoomIn{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}50%{opacity:1}}.zoomIn{animation-name:zoomIn}@keyframes zoomInDown{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,-1000px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInDown{animation-name:zoomInDown}@keyframes zoomInLeft{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(-1000px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(10px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInLeft{animation-name:zoomInLeft}@keyframes zoomInRight{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(1000px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(-10px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInRight{animation-name:zoomInRight}@keyframes zoomInUp{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,1000px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,-60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInUp{animation-name:zoomInUp}@keyframes zoomOut{0%{opacity:1}50%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}to{opacity:0}}.zoomOut{animation-name:zoomOut}@keyframes zoomOutDown{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,-60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,2000px,0);transform-origin:center bottom;animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomOutDown{animation-name:zoomOutDown}@keyframes zoomOutLeft{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(42px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale(.1) translate3d(-2000px,0,0);transform-origin:left center}}.zoomOutLeft{animation-name:zoomOutLeft}@keyframes zoomOutRight{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(-42px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale(.1) translate3d(2000px,0,0);transform-origin:right center}}.zoomOutRight{animation-name:zoomOutRight}@keyframes zoomOutUp{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,-2000px,0);transform-origin:center bottom;animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomOutUp{animation-name:zoomOutUp}@keyframes slideInDown{0%{transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translateZ(0)}}.slideInDown{animation-name:slideInDown}@keyframes slideInLeft{0%{transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translateZ(0)}}.slideInLeft{animation-name:slideInLeft}@keyframes slideInRight{0%{transform:translate3d(100%,0,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translateZ(0)}}.slideInRight{animation-name:slideInRight}@keyframes slideInUp{0%{transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translateZ(0)}}.slideInUp{animation-name:slideInUp}@keyframes slideOutDown{0%{transform:translateZ(0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(0,100%,0)}}.slideOutDown{animation-name:slideOutDown}@keyframes slideOutLeft{0%{transform:translateZ(0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)}}.slideOutLeft{animation-name:slideOutLeft}@keyframes slideOutRight{0%{transform:translateZ(0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0)}}.slideOutRight{animation-name:slideOutRight}@keyframes slideOutUp{0%{transform:translateZ(0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)}}.slideOutUp{animation-name:slideOutUp}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preview">

  <div class="navigation">

    <div class="open-panel border all">
      <span class="fa fa-chevron-right text"></span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center w-100 h-100 modal-wrapper">
    
    <div id="inner">

      <div class="navigation">

        <div class="close-panel border all">
          <span class="fa fa-chevron-left text"></span>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor blah, blah, blah...</div>

    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Just copying and pasting what I just said to @Chiller (:p)... While this solves the problem of not firing more than once, it was just a typo. In my UI this works perfectly, that typo was just preventing the demo snippet to work. My problem is with the closing animation which, if you check your code, still not sliding to the left. ;)

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Ahh I see!

Comment: @BrunoAugusto I've edited my answer for you! Check it out!

Comment: I tried blindly following just what you said you did in this update but it didn't work. However, after looking more carefully I noticed you removed the `left` from `#inner.closed`. I removed too and it worked. But why?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Sorry, I forgot to list that part in my explanation. Cause you want it to slide out to the left and if the starting point is `left: -62.6vw;` then there is no animation to see because to starting point is way too far to the left.

Comment: I see. That's about it then. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You were using **open** twice

```
$( '#inner' ).removeClass( 'open' ).addClass( 'open' );
```

When it should be

```
$( '#inner' ).removeClass( 'closed' ).addClass( 'open' );
```

> You can use transition to achieve what you want, no need for animation
>   classes

**See result:**

```js
$('#preview').addClass('open')

$('#preview .navigation .open-panel .fa').on('click', function() {
  $('#inner').removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
});

$('#inner .navigation .close-panel .fa').on('click', function() {
  $('#inner').addClass('closed').removeClass('open')
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 10vh !important;
}

#preview {
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 0.7vw;
  display: none;
  height: 80vh;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 31.3vw;
  background-color: blue;
}

#preview.open {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

#preview .navigation {
  position: absolute;
}

#preview .navigation .open-panel {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: none !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5vw;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.5vw;
}

#preview .navigation .open-panel .fa {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 6vh;
  margin: 2.1vh 0.25vw 1.45vh 0.4vw;
}

#inner {
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  height: 80vh;
  left: -100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 31.3vw;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.preview {
  position: relative;
}

#inner.open {
  left: 0;
}

#inner.closed {
  left: -100%;
}

#inner .navigation {
  right: 0 !important;
}

#inner .navigation .close-panel {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: none !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5vw;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.5vw;
}

#inner .close-panel .fa {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 6vh;
  margin: 2.1vh 0.4vw 1.45vh 0.25vw;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preview">

  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="open-panel border all">
      <span class="fa fa-chevron-right text"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center w-100 h-100 modal-wrapper wrapper">
    <div id="inner">
      <div class="navigation">
        <div class="close-panel border all">
          <span class="fa fa-chevron-left text"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor blah, blah, blah...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, while this solves the problem of not firing more than once, it was just a typo. In my UI this works perfectly, that typo was just preventing the demo snippet to work. My problem is with the closing animation which, if you check your code, still not sliding to the left. ;)

Comment: @BrunoAugusto i fixed the animation problem.. you can do the sliding effect with just transition no need for keyframe ... see my edit :)